# PHP Variable Interpolation

Tags: php, variables, string-interpolation

I have this html snippet:

```
<li>
  <a href="images/products/product-1.jpg" class="cloud-zoom-gallery" rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: 'images/products/product-1.jpg' ">
    <img src="images/products/product-1.jpg" alt = "Thumbnail 2"/>
  </a>
</li>
```

I want to make it dynamic and echo it in a PHP script, but it's not picking up the css/js effect. What could be wrong with the interpolation. This is my code:

```
echo '<li>
        <a href=product-images/'.$dpath. ' class="cloud-zoom-gallery" rel="useZoom:zoom1,smallImage:thumbs/'.$dpath.'"> 
       <img src=thumbs/'.$dpath.' alt = "'.$prod.'"/>
      </a>
     </li>';
```

Comment: Try `echo '<li><a href="product-images/'.$dpath. '"`.

Comment: You need to supply the doubt-quotes which HTML needs for defining attribute values.

Comment: You are not using variable interpolation at all but your code [should work](https://3v4l.org/Iji86) as long as the variables contain valid HTML-encoded strings with not white spaces (because you aren't sing quotes in those HTML attributes).

Comment: test it : <?php
$dpath='test.png';

echo '<li><a href=product-images/'.$dpath. ' class="cloud-zoom-gallery" rel="useZoom:zoom1,smallImage:thumbs/'.$dpath.'"> <img src="thumbs/'.$dpath.'" alt = "'.$prod.'"/></a></li>';

?>

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
echo '<li>
  <a href="images/products/product-1.jpg" class="cloud-zoom-gallery" rel="useZoom: \'zoom1\', smallImage: \'images/products/product-1.jpg\' ">
    <img src="images/products/product-1.jpg" alt = "Thumbnail 2"/>
  </a>
</li>';
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks